# iOS: How to find insertion position in sorted NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, sorting, insertion-sort

I have an NSMutableArray of sorted objects, which are displayed in a UITableView.

I want to insert a new object into the array and update the table view - which requires the index of the newly inserted object.

I can't find any system message to tell me the correct insertion index into the array which I need to update the table view.

The best I can find is:

- add new object
- sort
- using old copy of array, find the location of the new object (which requires searching)

or

- write my own search for insertion position

Surely, there must be a message to find the insertion position in a sorted array? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use `indexOfObject:inSortedRange:options:usingComparator:` method on the entire array. This method performs a binary search on a range that you pass, and gives you the insertion point when you use the `NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex` option:

```
NSUInteger insPoint = [myArray
    indexOfObject:toInsert
    inSortedRange:NSMakeRange(0, [myArray count])
    options:NSBinarySearchingInsertionIndex
    usingComparator:^(id lhs, id rhs) {
        return // return the result of comparing two objects
    }
];
```

Comment: Cool. I didn't know about that method. Thanks for sharing. (voted) As a relative old-timer in development, I continue to be amazed by the depth and breadth of the Cocoa frameworks.

Comment: WARNING: lhs and rhs switches randomly between "toInsert" and an actual object in the array. This means before doing beyond simple comparisons, you need to determine what lhs and rhs each represent

Comment: Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset/1417701-indexofobject?language=objc