# Display the array sequence from arrays of arrays

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am stuck at getting the array sequence from an NSMutableArray of NSDictionaries.

I am trying to get table view to display the NSDictionary position as inserted into the NSMutableArray.

NSMutableArray contains

```
NSDictionary1 contains NSString(Fabian), NSString(Toulouse), NSData(JPGFILE)
NSDictionary2 contains NSString(Kindle), NSString(May)     , NSData(PNGFILE)
NSDictionary3 contains NSString(Far)   , NSString(Ney)     , NSData(JPGFIle)
```

Tableview to display

```
S/no    First Name    Last Name       Image
 1        Fabian       Toulouse       JPGFILE   
 2        Kindle       May            PNGFILE
 3        Far          Ney            JPGFIle
```

I want to get "S/no" to display based on the sequence of insertion.

Help! Gurus!

Comment: What do you mean by you are stuck? What weird result that you see?

Comment: I meant I'm not able to get the S/No to display based on index of the array. I had [self.personsArray count]. It displays only the total count of NSDictionary in the NSMutableArray

Comment: Wait. I think I've got it.

Answer (score 0):

To do so, consider using [self.NSMutableArrayName indexOfObject: NSDictionary];

As it will return a number starting from 0, you will need to add 1.

```
1 + [self.NSMutableArrayName indexOfObject: NSDictionary];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the index of object please see this thread

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19647329/ios-how-to-find-insertion-position-in-sorted-nsmutablearray
```

or

```
[myArray indexOfObject:newDict];
```

Thanks.